# Mesmo utilizando "na.rm = TRUE" aparece a mensagem de erro dos missing values

Tags: r

Quando uso o comando para média de amostra complexas, aparece um aviso de que há missing values em weights, porém estou usando a opção `na.rm = TRUE`. Alguém sabe o que ocorre?

Segue o trecho:

```
svymean(basedados$variavel , svydesign( id = basedados$estrato , weight =     
        basedados$peso ),na.rm=TRUE)
> Erro em na.weight(data.frame(weights)) : missing values in `weights'
```

também testei esta versão e nada:

```
 svymean(dp$Dcoracao , svydesign( id = dp$V0024 , weight = dp$teste , na.rm = TRUE   
 ),na.rm=TRUE)
 > Erro em na.weight(data.frame(weights)) : missing values in `weights'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O argumento `na.rm` da funcão `svymean` se refere a valores omissos na variável sob a qual você está calculando a média (no seu caso, a variável `basedados$variavel` no primeiro exemplo e `dp$Dcoracao` no segundo exemplo).

Por outro lado, o erro está indicado que você tem valores omissos na variável de ponderação (variável `basedados$peso` no primeiro exemplo e `dp$teste` no segundo exemplo). Para resolver o problema, você precisará encontrar/imputar esses valores de alguma forma. Outra alternativa caso você não consiga fazer isso é remover os casos com valores omissos na sua variável de ponderação na função `svydesign`. Eu acho que não existe um argumento `na.rm` para função `svydesign`, mas você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
svymean(dp$Dcoracao , svydesign(id = dp[which(!is.na(dp$teste)),"V0024"], 
        weight = dp[which(!is.na(dp$teste)),"teste"])
```

Comment: Olá Rafael Nishimura, tentei usar o comando e apareceu outra mensagem de erro:

mean(bd$Dcoracao , svydesign(id = bd[which(!is.na(bd$teste)),"V0024"], weight = bd[which(!is.na(bd$teste)),"teste"]))
Erro em tapply(1:NROW(x), list(factor(strata)), function(index) { : 
  arguments must have same length
Além disso: Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
1: In x * pweights :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
2: In x * pweights :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
>